# Mysql nested while loop in a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, while-loop

currently i am working on one Stored Procedure in which i am using one while loop under another while loop. but i am not getting expected result. the most outer loop is iteration just one time.

I am trying following code.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `First_Sp` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `First_Sp`()
BEGIN

  DECLARE first_while_start  INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE second_while_start INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE first_while_count  INTEGER DEFAULT 3;
  DECLARE second_while_count INTEGER DEFAULT 3;

  WHILE first_while_start < first_while_count
  DO
    WHILE second_while_start < second_while_count
    DO
      SELECT concat(first_while_start,' - ',second_while_start) as result;
      SET second_while_start = second_while_start + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET first_while_start = first_while_start + 1;
  END WHILE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Result :

```
mysql> call first_sp();
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| 1 - 1  |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| 1 - 2  |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec).
```

I also Tried Repeat Loop. but still no LUCK.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `First_Sp` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `First_Sp`()
BEGIN

  DECLARE first_while_start  INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE second_while_start INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE first_while_count  INTEGER DEFAULT 3;
  DECLARE second_while_count INTEGER DEFAULT 3;

  REPEAT
    WHILE second_while_start < second_while_count
    DO
      SELECT concat(first_while_start,' - ',second_while_start) as result;
      SET second_while_start = second_while_start + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET first_while_start = first_while_start + 1;
  UNTIL first_while_start < first_while_count
  END REPEAT;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am not much of SQL Developer. I am trying.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because after the first iteration of the outer while loop the value of `second_while_start` is already `second_while_count` thus the inner loop does not execute as `second_while_start` is no longer less than `second_while_count`.

To get your "expected result" you need to reset second_while_start.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `First_Sp` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `First_Sp`()
BEGIN

  DECLARE first_while_start  INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE second_while_start INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE first_while_count  INTEGER DEFAULT 3;
  DECLARE second_while_count INTEGER DEFAULT 3;

  WHILE first_while_start < first_while_count
  DO
    WHILE second_while_start < second_while_count
    DO
      SELECT concat(first_while_start,' - ',second_while_start) as result;
      SET second_while_start = second_while_start + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET first_while_start = first_while_start + 1;
    /*here comes the important line:*/
    SET second_while_start = 1;
  END WHILE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Firstly, did not understand, and then did not understand again. Worked. Then understood 